# Convert IEEE std 830 format into class diagram

Tags: java, uml, class-diagram, metamodel

I have been trying to build a class diagram based on the following IEEE std 830 and as you can see the template format is big and there are could be a lot of classes to consider. The idea behind is to make a comparison between IEEE std 830 " SRS" template and REMM-based model.

I would appreciate your feedback and support.

Thank you.

Comment: You can not "convert" that. It's like Einstein has "converted" 3D space into relativity. You need your brain to do that. Vice versa you can spit out a SRS from a UML model.

Comment: @ThomasKilian Well ,thank you for your positive reply. I have already created the metamodel based on IEEE STD format.I will share it shortly.

Comment: So I assume your brain has warmed up :-) Thanks for sharing. I'll have a look into that.